# how to handle user cant post two times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to ask, i have a post and i want to handle it, if the users already has a post and user cant create again, he just can create one times, how i can handle it??  thank you

```
exports.show = async (req, res) => {

Store.find({ created_by: req.user._id })
    .populate("created_by", "_id store_name")
    .then(my_posts => {
        res.json({ my_posts })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })

const equal = Store.findOne({ created_by: req.user._id })
    .then(post => {
        res.json({ post })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })

if (req.user._id == equal) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `await` a function to get result of it in inline manner.

Try something like this

```js
exports.show = async (req, res) => {

const stored = await Store.find({ created_by: req.user._id })
    .populate("created_by", "_id store_name")

if (
  stored 
  && stored._id === req.body.store_id
  // && other conditions
) {
   // notify user that post already exists
}
```